# Blocking wp-login in HTACCESS has also blocked password protected pages

Tags: htaccess, security, password

We recently blocked all IP addresses except mine and the company owner's from getting to /wp-login.php except today we discovered this has inadvertently blocked any other password protected page. By password protected I mean using the WP built in password as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

This is the segment of HTACCESS that we added which did stop people WP-Login but has also stopped people from using the Password Protected

```
# Block access to wp-login.php.
<Files wp-login.php>
order deny,allow
allow from 192...(ip)
allow from 192...(ip)
deny from all
```

Would there be an easy work around so we can block /wp-login.php without blocking other password protected pages?

Comment: When you say it has stopped them from using Password Protected, do they get a 401 error page or what happens? If you remove those entries from `.htaccess`, do the password protected pages work again?

Comment: yes it throws up error page and yes as soon as I removed it the password protected page works again @AlexanderHolsgrove

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a Password Protected post uses the `wp-login.php` file to process the password authentication for a post. So your Apache snippet of blocking all but those specific IPs is going to apply to anything that is password protected as well.

[You can get nerdy and read code.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2.3/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1694) In here you can see that Post Password form's action is set to run that data through `wp-login.php?action=postpass`

So that is the bad news, BUT:

I wonder if trying to open that up so that your other files in WP can access those files? (I am just purely guessing at this point)

```
# Block access to wp-login.php.
<Files wp-login.php>
order deny,allow
allow from 192...(ip)
allow from 192...(ip)
allow from localhost
allow from 127.0.0.1
deny from all
```

I hope that helps or gives you some insight!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and I found a great solution.

This plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-password-plugin/

It allows you to create a link that basically includes the password in the link and when a user clicks it they are sent directly to the page without having to enter the password and without hitting the .htaccess screen.

So now I have password protected pages, .htaccess protection on the wp-login.php and instead of sending users an email with the password for the pages I just send the link with the token.